# C++ from unsigned char* to stringstream: Segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: stringstream, unsigned-char

I am writing a C++ code and trying to convert an `unsigned char*` array into a `string` using a `stringstream`.

the code snippet:

```
 unsigned char * arr;
 do{
    fill(*arr); 
    //if I print the array here, the print operation works fine
    stringstream s((const char*)arr); //I also tired other castings without success
    cout<<s.str()<<endl;

   //condition...
} while(condition);
```

The do-while because I have to repeat it. The problem is that I get a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error here: `stringstream s((const char*)arr);`

---

Here is a more detailled code. The `fill` is the `libusb_interrupt_transfer`

```
int len = 64;
int transferred;
unsigned char *pkt = new unsigned char[len];
unsigned char * arr;
int arrLen;

do {
    libusb_interrupt_transfer(handle, (EP_IN | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN), pkt, len, &transferred, 1000);

    arrLen = pkt[6];
    arr = new unsigned char[arrLen];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
        arr[i] = pkt[i+7];
    }
    stringstream s;
    s << (char*) arr;
}
```

Comment: What is "ret"?  Do you mean "arr"?

Comment: Do you ever initialise `arr` ? What does `fill` do ?

Comment: Can we assume that at some point, you actually allocate memory for `arr` to point at (e.g. `arr = new unsigned char[<something>]`)? Otherwise, it may be pointing at anything or nothing and invokes undefined behavior... Similarly, if the memory that `arr` points to is not null-terminated...

Comment: "fill" is just a function that fills the array. And the successive print shows that the array actually has elements.

Comment: @twalberg maybe it's because arr is not null terminated! Where i wrote `"fill"` indeed I am using function from `Libusb` that reads data from a USB device. So what you say could be probable. But how do I specify a null termination?

Comment: Please provide your `fill()` method. When I initialize it with clear `new[]`, it works properly. Moreover it seems like you don't `delete[]`

Comment: @Michał I edited my original message. You're right I don't  delete

Comment: @Michał is right - we need to see more code. The question is in jeopardy of closing due to insufficient information.

Comment: @jww I edited my original message

Comment: If my new answer doesn't work, please write how you print the output that it is ok, do you specify the length of printed element? Or simple `cout`?

Comment: Thank you for your solution @Michał but looks like there is a communication problem with the USB. I'm working on it, therefore I'll work on the protocol part as soon as I work the other problem out

Answer (score 1):

I would go with:

```
stringstream s;
s << (char*) arr;
```

**EDIT:**

Ok, so after you've given us your `Fill()` this is what I think makes the problem:

Basing on this link: http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__syncio.html#gac412bda21b7ecf57e4c76877d78e6486 you can **NEVER** assume that you will have the amount of chars passed in `len`. You should use your `transferred` to check how many chars have been transfered.

Directly problem is in the moment where you write

```
arrLen = pkt[6];
```

Because it is probable that pkt[6] has not been initialized. In this case it contains some random number which will (if we assume that the number is really random) give you a **1 to 2^31 - (64  - 7)** probability of access violation - if `arrLen` is too big, you will exceed `pkt` range pretty fast.

So I would suggest something like this:

```
libusb_interrupt_transfer(handle, (EP_IN | LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN), pkt, len, &transferred, 1000);

// AHTUNG! ATTENTION!
if (transferred >= 7) // and you'll need even more
    continue;
arrLen = pkt[6];
arr = new unsigned char[arrLen];
for (int i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
    arr[i] = pkt[i+7];
}
stringstream s;
s << (char*) arr;
```

Also, it would be nice to have `pkt` and `transferred` dumped in the moment of the error. This would make analyzing the problem more easily.

Comment: I tried also this, doesn't work